# postgreSQL backup tables and views

Tags: postgresql, backup, database-backups, pgadmin

I want to have backup of my database, but using pgadmin III I can only restore tables, but I want my views be restored as well. Is there any way doing that?

[image: by view I mean these]

tnx

Answer (score 0):

you could do this task with CLI, eg:

```
-bash-4.2$ pg_dump -s $(psql -c "select string_agg('-t '||relname,' ') from pg_class where relkind='v' and relnamespace='public'::regnamespace" -At) | grep -i create
CREATE VIEW avva AS
CREATE VIEW v AS
```

Of course without grep to get the full definition.

otherwise you have to repeat for every view

[image]

or create in schema backup, `DumpOptions #1` choose `Only Schema`...